# Add count + to iteration and keep counting foreach loop php

Tags: php

Im looking for a solution to add a + number to my iteration and keep the numeration after each loop end, what i have done now is the next, but this give me only a numeration start>end.

I have 3 rows, each row contain data, one of them will be inserted in the middle and will add an iteration number+.

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'data' => 'Good',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'data' => 'Equal',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'data' => 'Equal',
    )
);

$i = 1;
$concat = '';

foreach($data as $item){
    $count = $i++;

    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";

    if($item['data'] == 'Good'){
        //count Nr Reg 1 + 1 
        $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 2' . "\n";
        $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 2' . "\n";
    }

    //count Nr Reg 1 + Reg 2 if exist + 1 
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 3' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 3' . "\n";
}

echo '<pre>';
echo $concat;

/*
resut:
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 2
Nr. 1 - Reg 2
Nr. 1 - Reg 3
Nr. 1 - Reg 3

Nr. 2 - Reg 1
Nr. 2 - Reg 1
Nr. 2 - Reg 1
Nr. 2 - Reg 3
Nr. 2 - Reg 3

Nr. 3 - Reg 1
Nr. 3 - Reg 1
Nr. 3 - Reg 1
Nr. 3 - Reg 3
Nr. 3 - Reg 3

the result i need is:

Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 2 - Reg 2
Nr. 2 - Reg 2
Nr. 3 - Reg 3
Nr. 3 - Reg 3

Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 5 - Reg 3
Nr. 5 - Reg 3

Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 7 - Reg 3
Nr. 7 - Reg 3
*/
```

Comment: Just add `$count++` before each change of "reg"?

Comment: What i need is to store the value i added to the first iteration if Good exists!, then add to the Reg 1 + value i have added to Reg 2.

Comment: can you add an example, what is the expected result, and what you are currently getting

Comment: Is in my question the result it give me, and the result i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understant what exactly you want but to get result like in your comment you must change you code like that:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'data' => 'Good',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'data' => 'Equal',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3,
        'data' => 'Equal',
    )
);

$count = 0;
$concat = '';

foreach($data as $item){
    ++$count;
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 1' . "\n";

    if($item['data'] == 'Good'){
        ++$count;
        //count Nr Reg 1 + 1 
        $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 2' . "\n";
        $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 2' . "\n";
    }

    //count Nr Reg 1 + Reg 2 if exist + 1
    ++$count;
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 3' . "\n";
    $concat .= 'Nr. '.$count.' - Reg 3' . "\n";
}
```

//result:

```
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 1 - Reg 1
Nr. 2 - Reg 2
Nr. 2 - Reg 2
Nr. 3 - Reg 3
Nr. 3 - Reg 3
Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 4 - Reg 1
Nr. 5 - Reg 3
Nr. 5 - Reg 3
Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 6 - Reg 1
Nr. 7 - Reg 3
Nr. 7 - Reg 3
```

Comment: Is what i want, the only thing is that on //count Nr Reg 1 + 1 it give me 2 and 3 then it goes to 5

Comment: I have edited your question and i've added the result you give me and what i need.

Comment: Then I have edited it too and I think this result is same what you write in you question.